# different responses in API and when using `fetch()`

Tags: next.js, typeorm

I have next js app with the following entity inside database:

```
@Entity()
export class HomeworkEntity {
  @PrimaryGeneratedColumn('uuid')
  id: string;

  comments: Array<CommentEntity>;
}
```

I have a method to fetch homework:

```
  @ApiGet(':id', {
    useAuthGuard: false,
    type: OutputHomeworkDto,
    description: 'Get homework by id or slug without solution',
  })
  async findById(@Param() params: InputIdDto) {
    const homework = await this._homeworkService.findOne(
      {
        where: isUUID(params.id) ? { id: params.id } : { slug: params.id },
      },
      true,
    );

    homework.comments = await this._commentService.findByTargetId(homework.id);
    
    return homework;
  }
```

while in API (swagger) the response includes the `comments` array, when I fetch it inside my app, the comments are empty. What might be the reason? Below is how I'm calling it?

```
async function getDataTest(id: string) {
  const res = await fetch(`${process.env.NEXT_PUBLIC_API_URL}/homework/${id}`);

  if (!res.ok) {
    throw new Error('Failed to fetch data');
  }

  return (await res.json()) as any;
}
```

Any ideas?